# 3 Models Entity Joins in AppEngine Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've read a lot about how I need to rethink implementing entities and joins when developing for AppEngine, and I still can't figure out how to do this:

I've 3 entities. **Tag** has many **Tweets** and **User** Follow many **Tags**.

I would like to get all Tweets that is Tagged with tags that a User follows.

I thought eliminating Tags entity and using **StringListProperty** might work as this:

```
Tweets.all().filter(‘tag IN”, user.tags)
```

However, as in the ListProperty [documentations](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#ListProperty) indicated, this won’t work! as because a query can’t compare two lists.

> A query cannot compare two list values. There is no way to test two lists for equality without testing each element for membership separately.

Any idea how to structure the entities in order I can be able to answer the question:

> How to get all Tweets that is Tagged with **tags** that a User follows?

Thanks

Comment: This Google I/O talk covers this subject really well.  I believe he goes over how he would implement a twitter-like service in App Engine: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AgaL6NGpkB8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not trying to compare two lists - you're checking for intersection. The query you list will do that, with one major caveat: IN filters are split up into multiple sub-queries, which are executed independently by the backend, with a maximum of 30 sub-queries.

That is, if your user follows 3 tags ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], doing the above is equivalent the union of:

```
Tags.all().filter('tag =', 'foo')
Tags.all().filter('tag =', 'bar')
Tags.all().filter('tag =', 'baz')
```

Comment: Interesting. So my query would actually work, but it would be expensive? Problem is if it will execute as you explained then all the tweets won't be sorted out? Is there a documentation of the information you gave above? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Mohammad Correct. What do you mean by "all the tweets won't be sorted out"?

Comment: I mean the accumulated tweets from the three queries you put will be not be whole sorted together, on creation date for example? I have to do it in memory, right?

Comment: @Mohammad The code that executes the sub-queries does a merge-join on the results of the individual queries, returning them in sorted order.

Comment: This works great. Thank you! But I doubt it's scalability. I've seen the Google I/O techtalk that @Calvin recommended and I am going to try to implement some of the tips he noted. But would appreciate if anyone have any other tips on how to make this scale better and use less CPU time.

Answer (score 0):

You should find this [article](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling.html) on managing entity relationships helpful.

Since each Tweet can have more than one tag, you'll need to follow the "Many to Many" section of this article. You'll probably want do the same thing for relationships between Users and Tags.  This will then give you an efficient way to get all Tweets corresponding to Tags followed by a User.

Comment: I have actually read this couple of time. And I understand how the many-to-many relation can be implemented in AppEngine entities, and already done that with couple of other projects. But I still can't figure out how to intersect 3 many-to-many relations.